# dataframe overwritten when using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create four new pandas dataframes via a list comprehension.  Each new dataframe should be the original 'constituents_list' dataframe with two new columns.  These two columns add a defined number of years to an existing column and return the value.  The example code is below

```
def add_maturity(df, tenor):
    df['tenor'] = str(tenor) + 'Y'
    df['maturity'] = df['effectivedate'] + pd.DateOffset(years=tenor)
    return df

year_list = [3, 5, 7, 10]
new_dfs = [add_maturity(constituents_file, tenor) for tenor in year_list]
```

My expected output in in the new_dfs list should have four dataframes, each with a different value for 'tenor' and 'maturity'.  In my results, all four dataframes have the same data with 'tenor' of '10Y' and a 'maturity' that is 10 years greater than the 'effectivedate' column.

I suspect that each time I iterate through the list comprehension each existing dataframe is overwritten with the latest call to the function.  I just can't work out how to stop this happening.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're assigning to the DataFrame object, you're modifying in place. And when you pass it as an argument to a function, what you're passing is a reference to the DataFrame object, in this case a reference to the *same* DataFrame object every time, so that's overwriting the previous results.

To solve this issue, you can either create a copy of the DataFrame at the start of the function:

```
def add_maturity(df, tenor):
    df = df.copy()
    df['tenor'] = str(tenor) + 'Y'
    df['maturity'] = df['effectivedate'] + pd.DateOffset(years=tenor)
    return df
```

(Or you could keep the function as is, and have the *caller* copy the DataFrame first when passing it as an argument...)

Or you can use the `assign()` method, which returns a new DataFrame with the modified columns:

```
def add_maturity(df, tenor):
    return df.assign(
        tenor= str(tenor) + 'Y',
        maturity=df['effectivedate'] + pd.DateOffset(years=tenor),
    )
```

(Personally, I'd go with the latter. It's similar to how most DataFrame methods work, in that they typically return a new DataFrame rather than modifying it in place.)

Comment: Thanks filbranden, this makes perfect sense.  Particularly like your use of df.assign